# Looking for "Mémoire sur Monsieur Vianney" by Catherine Lassagne (First Biographer of the Saint)

Tags: catholicism, reference-request, st-john-vianney

According to the [Sanctuaire d'Ars webpage](https://www.arsnet.org/Catherine-Lassagne.html), Catherine Lassagne recorded her many recollections of St. John Vianney in a small book entitled, "Mémoire sur Monsieur Vianney". It was subsequently revived a couple of times--the last being in 1867, eight years after the death of the Curé of Ars.

In the above link, she is referred to as the first biographer of the Saint.

QUESTION: I have long sought the availability of this book online (an archived edition) but without success. Does anyone know if such a PDF exists online that one may access? I have tried various titles, such as *Petit mémoire*, which is how Msgr. Trochu refers to the book in his popular biography of the Saint, The Curé of Ars, currently published by TAN Books.

*Note:* I am looking for an accessible online version of the book. There is a paperback "Au Quotidien", which may be the same book with a different title---but I am not interested in that one. Rather, I wish to find a photocopy of an unedited (unabridged) original.